# Como resolver erro de syntax

Tags: php

Um formulario com anexo que erra no envio, na linha 14. alguem ajuda

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"];
// Para quem vai ser enviado o email
$para = "eadamaral[@]gmail.com";
$boundary = "XYZ-".date("dmYis")."-ZYX";
$fp = fopen($arquivo["tmp_name"], "rb"); // abre o arquivo enviado
$anexo = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo["tmp_name"])); // calcula o tamanho
$anexo = base64_encode($anexo); // codifica o anexo em base 64
fclose($fp); // fecha o arquivo
// cabeçalho do email
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary="$boundary"\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";
// email
$mensagem  = "--$boundary\n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
$mensagem .= "<strong>Nome: </strong> $nome \r\n";
$mensagem .= "--$boundary \n";
// anexo
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."; name="".$arquivo['name']."" \n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="".$arquivo['name']."" \r\n";
$mensagem .= "$anexo \n";
$mensagem .= "--$boundary \n";
// enviar o email
mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Não poste seu código em forma de imagem. O [pt.so] tem suporte para códigos, basta você colar seu código no editor da pergunta, selecioná-lo e pressionar o atalho `Ctrl+K`. Você pode, também, utilizar o botão `{}` do editor. Por favor, entre em [edit] e faça a alteração.

Comment: Desculpe Anderson, mas não conseguir, mesmo assim vou tentar novamente.

Comment: Então recomendo que faça antes de qualquer coisa o [tour] pelo site para aprender pelo menos o básico de como o site funciona. Nele você encontrará guias de como formatar corretamente suas perguntas e respostas.

Answer (score 2):

A forma que o PHP trabalha com concatenação de strings, é a seguinte:

```
$var2 = "concatenado";
$var = "texto" . $var2 . "mais texto";
```

Perceba que há um ponto onde há o fechamento das aspas duplas e a variável. Você pode encontrar mais exemplos na documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php

Uma alternativa ao uso o '.', que é relativamente criticado por programadores de outras linguagens, é concatenar dessa forma:

```
$var2 = "concatenado";
$var = "texto {$var2}";
```

Lembrando que o exemplo anterior só funcionará em strings entre aspas duplas ('"'). Aspas simples (''') não vai concatenar o valor da variável $var2, simplesmente vai aparecer "{$var2}" no fim da string.

Comment: Mesmo assim não consegui corrigir Amadeus, me ajuda nessa cara, preciso urgente dessas correções.!

Comment: @Dias na linha 14, a concatenação está feita de forma errada. Você corrigiu isso?

Comment: nao... desculpe. como faço?

Comment: @Dias, dê uma olhada na minha resposta. A sua solução está no primeiro exemplo que dei

Comment: Sou iniciante, e estou estudando PHP agora, para mim é muito recente ainda... mas entendo seu enpenho para que eu possa aprender, mas não conseguir identificar o ponto.

Answer (score 1):

Na linha 14 falta "escapar" as aspas dentro "das aspas":

```
$headers .= "boundary="$boundary"\r\n";
```

Faça isto:

```
$headers .= "boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
```

Também é necessário escapar as aspas na linha 22:

```
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."; name="".$arquivo['name']."" \n";
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."; name=\"".$arquivo['name']."\" \n";
```

Também é necessário escapar as aspas na linha 24:

```
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="".$arquivo['name']."" \r\n";
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo['name']."\" \r\n";
```

O código corrigido deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"];
// Para quem vai ser enviado o email
$para = "eadamaral[@]gmail.com";
$boundary = "XYZ-".date("dmYis")."-ZYX";
$fp = fopen($arquivo["tmp_name"], "rb"); // abre o arquivo enviado
$anexo = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo["tmp_name"])); // calcula o tamanho
$anexo = base64_encode($anexo); // codifica o anexo em base 64
fclose($fp); // fecha o arquivo
// cabeçalho do email
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";
// email
$mensagem  = "--$boundary\n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
$mensagem .= "<strong>Nome: </strong> $nome \r\n";
$mensagem .= "--$boundary \n";
// anexo
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."; name=\"".$arquivo['name']."\" \n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo['name']."\" \r\n";
$mensagem .= "$anexo \n";
$mensagem .= "--$boundary \n";
// enviar o email
mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);
```